# Spliting string by substring and putting it to array bash

Tags: bash, awk, split

How to split a string by substring using bash and put the result into an array? The string may contain different number of substring depending on system input. So far I testet peace od code without system input

```
String1="SuperDomain/Off/01|stack SuperDomain/Off/03|apply"
echo $String1 | awk '{split($0,a,"SuperDomain"); print a[1]}'
```

and it doesn't show anything. I want to use whole array and don't know in fact nie many substrings I get from input.

Comment: It shows something. It shows an empty field, which is what you have in your sample string.

Comment: `for (i in a) print a[i]}` maybe?

Comment: Ok, so how to fix it?

Comment: Are elements of the final array always going to be delimited by spaces, and you just want to remove the part before the first /?

Comment: And are you talking about a bash array, or an awk array?

Comment: In array I want to have strings /Off/01|stack, /Off/03|apply. In some cases there are more spaces in the string when the input data shows an error. I looks like /SuperDomain/Off/01|error before %%data%% so I can't use space as delimiter.

Comment: There is nothing to fix. Everything is working as expected. This is how your input is. If you need different output, give different input.

Comment: The strings you are looking for are in the following positions in the array. `a[2]` and `a[3]`

Answer (score 0):

Since according to your example code, you are obviously willing to use `awk` (though in your question you are asking for a bash solution), this one would work in your concrete example:

```
arr=( $(awk -F SuperDomain '{ print $2; print $3 }' <<<"$String1") )
```

This populates the bash array `arr` with the elements `/Off/01|stack` and `/Off/03|apply`. For the general case (i.e. if you are not interested in just the fields 2 and 3 like in your example), you would would of course write an awk loop to print out all fields.

When you do this, you need to make up your mind what to do with empty fields. For instance, if `String1` contains `'SuperDomainfooSuperDomainSuperDomainbar'`, you need to decide whether your resulting bash array should have 2  elements ('foo' 'bar'), or 3 or maybe 4 elements.

Another point to keep in mind with this approach is, that the field separator of awk (i.e. the argument to the `-F` option) is interpreted as regular expression. Hence if you want to break up your string along fixed separators, which contain special regexp characters, you would would have to escape them.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement are not completely clear. From the sample input, I would read the requirements as

- Using only bash
- Split the input into space separated tokens
- For each token, extract the data by stripping the leading "SuperDomain" prefix
- place into Bash Array

Note that this is "pure-bash" solution - no awk, sed or external proess.

```
String1="SuperDomain/Off/01|stack SuperDomain/Off/03|apply"
# Split into array
read -a data <<< "$String1"

# Strip the prefix from each element
a=( "${data[@]#SuperDomain}" )

# Show the final array
declare -p a
```

Result:
declare -a a=([0]="/Off/01|stack" [1]="/Off/03|apply")